# Prove iCloud document ownership

Tags: icloud, apple-id, file-sharing

How can I prove that I own the account in which an iCloud document is stored?

One possible solution could be if a) there is a public key available for every iCloud user, so that the user could sign his public key, publish this on his iCloud and share this file. If I can b) retreive the owner account of this file, I can get his public key and verify the ownership.

Is this possible? Is there another way / an easier way to achieve this goal?

Comment: To what end? Proving you own the box doesn't prove you own the contents.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the 'goal' is. Are you trying to digitally sign a document? Or protect it or restrict access in some way? What kind of document?

Comment: @benwiggy In the end, I try to find way to create a zero knowledge proof that I do own a given mail address. Since every iCloud account is connected to a (verified) e-Mail address, only the owner of this e-mail-address can publish a file to this iCloud account. 
If a third party can obtain any information associated to _the account of a published file_, it is possible to proof that I indeed am the owner of this account.

Comment: @Tetsujin I only want to prove that I am able to publish within this account. If you share a secret with me and send you back an Url of a file containing a MD5 hash of that secret, then you know that I own the account.

Comment: This doesn't prove you "own" a particular email address, as anyone who has the password can access it.

Comment: Simple proof you own an email address is to answer an email to it. More complex proof that you are *rightful* owner requires 2FA. You have not only the password, but a piece of hardware already assigned to it… this of course will also fail if you 'stole' an account that wasn't already protected this way & set it to your own 2FA device before the rightful owner noticed. 'Proving' without doubt to a 3rd party is really not easy.

Comment: Do you need to change the title to reflect ownership of email address? For proving ownership of email address have a read of this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233968/zero-knowledge-proof-of-ownership-of-an-email-address#234408 As @Tetsujin says it is not easy.